# Can't seem to turn off a device using dev.off() in R

Tags: r, pdf, jupyter

I'm using Jupyter notebooks running an R kernel (3.2.2) in OSX, working through some basic stats exercises. A few days ago I played with ggplot for the first time, and ran some commands from a notebook cell experimenting with printing to pdf files, in other words using something like the following: `pdf("file.pdf"); plot(x, y); dev.off()`  I didn't keep any of those cell contents, so I can't see exactly what I ran but I imagine it is possible I create some pdfs and didn't include a dev.off() command?

My problem is, since that session, now every cell I run in any notebook (including new blank ones) generates an unwanted pdf file. If that code involves plotting a figure, the pdf contains that figure, if the code is anything else, the pdf created is unable to be opened. I can't find any way, elegant or brutish, to stop these pdfs from being created.

If I go to a new blank notebook:

running `dev.list()` returns `pdf: 2`
running `dev.cur()` returns `pdf: 2`
running `dev.off()` returns `null device: 1`

but then, if immediately after, I run either `dev.list()` or `dev.cur()` again, they again return `pdf: 2`

I am able to open additional new devices, and `dev.off()` succeeds in closing them. But this `pdf: 2` device won't go away. I tried terminating all my sessions, rebooting my machine, etc., to no avail; Suggestions?

Additionally, If I run a pdf() command from a console in Terminal (i.e., not from a notebook), my plots show as being generated by Quartz; I understand this might be a Quartz problem and not an R problem, but my question remains, how do I close this device, or otherwise stop all these pdfs from being created?

Comment: Have you tried running the dev.off() command twice? dev.off();dev.off() Sometimes I find I have to close an extra device, even though I didn't open an extra one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I hadn't done this, but it doesn't work. it returns `Error in dev.off(): cannot shut down device 1 (the null device)` and then, as before, `dev.list()` and `dev.off()` continue to return `pdf: 2`

Comment: Be aware that at least one device needs to be active, so if you try to close the last one you will get an error. But if you have several devices open, you can use dev.off() to close some of them.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a problem when a `sink()` has been opened but not closed, perhaps because an error occurred before the closing code was reached.

Try this to plug an open sink:

```
sink(NULL)
ht @mdsumner
```

Answer (score 0):

```
graphics.off()
```

should forcefully close all devices. Check out [this page](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eanderson/rw1001/library/base/html/dev.html) for more useful information.